# MS SQL - Where are the syntax and scalar errors?

Tags: sql-server, variables, syntax-error, scalar

I've been beating my head over this brick wall all morning.  This is a very simplified example of the error(s) I've been receiving.  I am using SSMS.

```
DECLARE @myid nvarchar(10) = '5'
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2048) = 'SELECT id FROM Applications A WHERE A.id=@myid'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @myid=@myid
```

Errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '5'. Msg 137,
>   Level 15, State 2, Line 1 Must declare the scalar variable "@myid".

Why am I getting the syntax, and scalar errors?  @myid is defined, right?

Comment: please close the question, if you have got the right answer

Comment: You shouldn't be using dynamic sql in this query. it is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sp_executesql` needs to receive a definition of the parameters, which you are missing. So, in your case, you should use:

```
DECLARE @myid nvarchar(10) = '5';
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2048) = 'SELECT id FROM Applications A WHERE A.id=@myid';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@myid nvarchar(10)', @myid=@myid;
```

Comment: Yep, that did it!  Thank you.